# Lime Survey after user logged in with his token to participate in survey, a separate session is maintained for users?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, limesurvey

After User logged in with his token to participate in the survey. A separate logged in session is created in the lime survey application ??

If so where the session is set in the source code of lime survey.

I need to keep the survey in save/edit mode. so that user can login and edit his survey any time (multiple times) before the end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way : use token

- Allow multiple responses or update responses with one token?
- Enable token-based response persistence

See LimeSurvey manual : https://manual.limesurvey.org/Survey_settings#Tokens

Hardest way : do a plugin using beforeSurveyPage https://manual.limesurvey.org/BeforeSurveyPage and get some code from LS core : https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/master/application/helpers/frontend_helper.php#L14

PS:
And to get the survey session information : `Yii::app()->session["survey_{$iSurveyId}"];` replace $iSurveyId by the survey id.